# BindingSource filters not working

Tags: c#, database, winforms, binding

The filters work for myTicketsSubmitButton but not work allTicketsSubmitButton. The code is the same but I don't understand why it works for one method and not another.

I am using WinForms and C# with Visual Studio 2010

```
    private void myTicketsSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT u.CallerName, t.* FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t ON u.id = t.user WHERE u.CallerName = '" + Environment.UserName.ToLower() + "'";
        GetData(sqlQuery);

        if (myTicketsAllRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus LIKE '%'";
        }

        if (myTicketsClosedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Closed'";
        }

        if (myTicketsOpenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Open'";                
        }
    }

    private void allTicketsSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT u.CallerName, t.* FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t ON u.id = t.user";
        GetData(sqlQuery);

        if (myTicketsAllRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus LIKE '%'";
        }

        if (myTicketsClosedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Closed'";
        }

        if (myTicketsOpenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Open'";               
        }
    }

    private void GetData(string selectCommand) 
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        try 
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a  
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample 
            // database accessible to your system.
            String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\testdb.accdb";

            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query. 
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and 
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to 
            // update the database. 
            OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource. 
            DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
            dataAdapter.Fill(table); 
            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
            ticketsBindingSource = bindingSource1;

            // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content. 
            //ticketsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);                

            ticketsDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }
        catch(OleDbException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the connectionString variable with a connection string that is valid for your system.");
        }
    }
```

I have 6 Radio buttons.

3 of them are for myTickets
--Open
--Closed
--All

3 of them are for allTickets
--Open
--Closed
--All

When I click the radio buttons for myTickets group, everything works

I made a small change to the code but the allTicketsSubmitButton doesn't display all the tickets for Open or All tickets.

The database is relatively small so I can quickly test things as I go.

I have 5 entries
2 Open
2 Closed
1 Work In Progress

2 Entries are assigned to another user (so 3 of them are myTickets).

I noticed something weird

The results display correctly ONLY if I set the radio button for myTickets and allTickets to the same thing

(both open will display the open tickets)
if one is open and the other is closed,  then nothing happens

Comment: what is not working?  are you getting an error? Does the data fill your grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 6 radio buttons, 3 for the myTickets and 3 for allTickets then why do you have your myTickets being checked under your allTickets button click event?

I think you need to change your code from:

```
private void allTicketsSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT u.CallerName, t.* FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t ON u.id = t.user";

        if (myTicketsAllRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus LIKE '%'";
        }

        if (myTicketsClosedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Closed'";
        }

        if (myTicketsOpenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            GetData(sqlQuery);
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Open'";               
        }
    }
```

TO:

```
private void allTicketsSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT u.CallerName, t.* FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t ON u.id = t.user";
        GetData(sqlQuery); // move this here, you only need this in one place

        if (allTicketsAllRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus LIKE '%'";
        }

        if (allTicketsClosedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Closed'";
        }

        if (allTicketsOpenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            ticketsBindingSource.Filter = "ProblemStatus = 'Open'";               
        }
    }
```

Comment: i changed the code to your recommendation but still have the same issue

Comment: did you update the names of the radio buttons under the event click?

Comment: all the names of the radiobuttons are updated and are correct. I made sure it wasnt misspelled or capitalized

Comment: if you place a break point on the dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString); is the query correct?  I just created a test app with the code for each radio button and the filter is working properly for all 6 buttons